# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable. ARR and NLB

Tags: iis, http-status-code-503, arr, nlb

friends!
I have a problem with my web site on IIS with ARR and NLB.
I set up IIS, ARR and NLB on Win Server 2016. Using DefaultWebSite.
The site is accessible locally but not accessible from the second server that is in the ARR farm.

Shows error on the second server: HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
On the first server all good working (local).

I have tried restarting the IIS server and app pool: DefaultAppPool

Comment: This error usually means that the website itself is running, but the application pool associated with the website is stopped. If you see the application pool stop again after requesting the page, check your event viewer for an error entry explaining why it stopped the pool. Related document: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/http-response-503-service-unavailable-from-iis-one-common/ba-p/1720007

Comment: No.  The application pool dont stop. Just cant connect from anover farm-server to site. 503 error from the second server in browser.
No firewall.

Comment: Try using FRT to view details about the 503 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis